# How to pull information from a .json file on wordpress

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress

I have a [website](http://newsite.alcoholanalytics.com/become-a-pos-partner/)  with a contact form.

The form has a field called `POS Company Name`". I need to populate this field with items that I need to pull from a `.json` file.

```js
[
    {
        "name": "POSitouch",
        "supportedVersions": [
            "5.36+",
            "6.36+",
            "QuickMenu 2.6.7.12+"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Aloha",
        "supportedVersions": [
            "5.1+"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Posera Maitre'D",        
        "supportedVersions": [
            "7.0"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Veloce",
        "supportedVersions": [
            "6.x",
            "7.x",
            "8.x",
            "9.x"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Azbar AZPos",
        "supportedVersions": [
            "6.x",
            "7.x",
            "8.x"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Dinerware",    
        "supportedVersions": [
            "3.x"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Micros 3700",        
        "supportedVersions": [
            "RES4",
            "RES5"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Micros Simphony",        
        "supportedVersions": [
            "1.6+"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Micros First Edition",        
        "supportedVersions": [
            "1.6+"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "EPOS Now",        
        "supportedVersions": [
            "All Versions"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Maxirest",        
        "supportedVersions": [
            "4.9+"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Silverware",        
        "supportedVersions": [
            "Avrio",
            "Legacy"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "OKPOS",        
        "supportedVersions": [
            "All Versions"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Tiller",        
        "supportedVersions": [
            "All Versions"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Tango",
        "supportedVersions": [
            "All Versions"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Zonal",       
        "supportedVersions": [
            "Aztec 3.6+"
        ]       
    },
    {
        "name": "Lavu",
        "supportedVersions": [
            "All Versions"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Bepoz/Vectron",       
        "supportedVersions": [
            "4.3+"
        ]       
    },
    {
        "name": "EasyPos",
        "supportedVersions": [
            "All Versions"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "IdealPos",       
        "supportedVersions": [
            "7.x+"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "H&L",
        "supportedVersions": [
            "8+"
        ]
    }
]
```

When a user clicks this field, it needs to show the list of items that are displayed in the `.json file.` The website can pull this data and store it locally in file or db, or call it on every request.

Comment: Your question is not being well received as you're not showing an attempt to solve the problem, you're just describing a feature request... That said, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43773195/1287812) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13638937/1287812) for some solutions.

Answer (score -1):

You can user a function with for loop to insert in wordpress html.

```js
window.onload = function load (){
console.log ('readyu');

var json = [
    {
        "name": "POSitouch",
        "supportedVersions": [
            "5.36+",
            "6.36+",
            "QuickMenu 2.6.7.12+"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Aloha",
        "supportedVersions": [
            "5.1+"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Posera Maitre'D",        
        "supportedVersions": [
            "7.0"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Veloce",
        "supportedVersions": [
            "6.x",
            "7.x",
            "8.x",
            "9.x"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Azbar AZPos",
        "supportedVersions": [
            "6.x",
            "7.x",
            "8.x"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Dinerware",    
        "supportedVersions": [
            "3.x"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Micros 3700",        
        "supportedVersions": [
            "RES4",
            "RES5"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Micros Simphony",        
        "supportedVersions": [
            "1.6+"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Micros First Edition",        
        "supportedVersions": [
            "1.6+"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "EPOS Now",        
        "supportedVersions": [
            "All Versions"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Maxirest",        
        "supportedVersions": [
            "4.9+"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Silverware",        
        "supportedVersions": [
            "Avrio",
            "Legacy"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "OKPOS",        
        "supportedVersions": [
            "All Versions"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Tiller",        
        "supportedVersions": [
            "All Versions"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Tango",
        "supportedVersions": [
            "All Versions"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Zonal",       
        "supportedVersions": [
            "Aztec 3.6+"
        ]       
    },
    {
        "name": "Lavu",
        "supportedVersions": [
            "All Versions"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Bepoz/Vectron",       
        "supportedVersions": [
            "4.3+"
        ]       
    },
    {
        "name": "EasyPos",
        "supportedVersions": [
            "All Versions"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "IdealPos",       
        "supportedVersions": [
            "7.x+"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "H&L",
        "supportedVersions": [
            "8+"
        ]
    }
];

function read (){
  for (var i=0; i<json.length; i++){
    // console.log('name: ', json[i].name);  //to write it in the console
    // console.log('version: ', json[i].supportedVersions[0]); //to write it in the console
    document.write(' name: ', json[i].name, "<BR>"); //to write it in html
    document.write(' version: ', json[i].supportedVersions[0], "<BR><BR>"); //to write it in html
  }
}

read();
}
```

Comment: This looks like a straightforward way! How would you go about pulling this list into the form field?